# Why deleting system files on a rooted Android says "device or resource is busy"?

Tags: root-access, file-system, mount, system-apps, delete

I have FX Explorer, I was trying to delete some stuff in `/system/app` (the stuff are just empty folders) but it keep saying `The operation isn't permitted on a mounted filesystem`. What should I do to fix this?

(This issue is new, I used to delete whatever I want without problems)

I tried with the terminal, it says `device or resource is busy`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using **Magisk modules**, you must be trying to delete a bind mounted <sup>([1](https://topjohnwu.github.io/Magisk/details.html#magic-mount))</sup> directory. Enable **Core Only Mode** (no modules) in Magisk app and reboot. Then delete the stuff you want to.